# Struts 2.2.3 dojo form submit

Tags: forms, struts2, dojo, submit

I'm trying to implement a form submission using ajax in struts 2.2.3.
I imported dojo plugin library to ma project and this is how my jsp looks like.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <sx:head/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="container">
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />
<s:actionerror/>
    <s:form action="Login" method="post">
         <s:textfield name="username" label="User Name"/>
         <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
         <s:submit type="submit" align="right" />
    </s:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there is nothing using "sx" here. Right now the jsp works fine with refreshing the page. I want data to be sent using ajax (without refreshing the page). What should i modified to achieve that? It would be really helpful if anyone can provide me a link to an example or a tutorial which shows struts2 with ajax FORM SUBMIT.

Comment: Did you see `Tag Reference` of **[dojo submit](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/dojo-submit.html)**?

Comment: Do you have any investment in dojo currently? Have you considered jQuery + Struts2 JSON plugin? If you don't have an investment in dojo I would recommend the later.

Comment: nope i haven't started yet. I can think of using jQuery + Struts2 JSON plugin. Can u direct me to a good tutorial to begin?

Answer (score 1):

using sx:submit instead of s:submit

```
<s:form action="Login" method="post" id="form1">
     <s:textfield name="username" label="User Name"/>
     <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
     <sx:submit align="right" targets="form1" />
</s:form>
```